# sbt retrieveManaged doesn't pick up jars produced using publish-local

Tags: scala, sbt

Suppose I have a project in which I've used `sbt publish-local` to generate local copies of the jar files in `~/.ivy2/local`.

Another sbt project on the same machine can successfully locate these jars to satisfy dependencies. However, if in that project I use the option `retrieveManaged := true`, sbt never copies the jars out of `~/.iv2/local` into the `lib_managed` directory.

> How can I make this happen? (Is this behaviour intended?)

(I'm using sbt 0.12.1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the same setup. When I update my locally published dependencies, I remove the managed jars first and then run the update:

```
$ rm -r lib_managed/jars/my-package-prefix
$ sbt test:compile
```

(`test:compile` will figure out that the jars are missing and do the `update` by itself).

In older versions of sbt I believe there was an issue when using `-SNAPSHOT` versions, but I haven't seen this problem anymore with sbt 0.12.

In rare situations, something messes up with the Ivy cache and somehow you cannot enforce the updates. This is perhaps the case when corrupt Ivy meta data files have been used. Then the only solution is to wipe all occurrences of your dependency from `~/.ivy2/local` and `~/.ivy2/cache`, re-publish, and re-update.

Comment: In a quick test I did with sbt 0.12.2, it looks like things in local get pulled into lib_managed.  If you can show a case where the `rm -r` is required, it is probably a bug that can be fixed.